# Symfony check user provider

Tags: php, symfony

I have overriden the `onAuthenticationSuccess` function to do somethings if login ok.

In this function, I can get my user with : `$token->getUser()`.

In my `security.yml`, I have two different providers : `fos_userbundle` for my application, and `in_memory` for admin.

How can I know if the user is using `in_memory` provider or not ? I need to check that because I don't want to do a special action if I tried to login with a user in_memory..

Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

You can check the class the user object is of. The `in_memory` provider uses the `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User` class while FOSUserBundle provides its own `User` class (depending on the used database driver).